"module "MyQmlDll" is not installed" error when importing the DLL in a project
I've got 2 projects, a DLL, and a main project.
Importing the DLL into the main project causes this error before starting the application:

QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/MainP/main.qml:2:1: module "MyQmlDll" is not installed


Below is the DLL project structure, code, and main structure.
DLL:
MyLibrary:
 |
  - MyLibrary.pro
  - qml.qrc
  - qmldir
  - main.cpp
  - src: 
   |
    - myclass.h
    - myclass.cpp
    - MyLibrary_global.h
    - myqmlobject.qml
  - lib:
   | 
    - MyQmlDll.dll

Mylibrary.pro:
    CONFIG += dll
    TARGET = MyQmlDll
    TEMPLATE = lib
    SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        src/myclass.cpp    
    HEADERS += \
        src/MyLibrary_global.h \
        src/myclass.h
    # Include path for QML
    RESOURCES += qml.qrc
    # Define output path
    DESTDIR = $$PWD/lib
    DISTFILES += \
        qmldir

myclass.h:
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QQmlEngine>

class MyClass : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    QML_ELEMENT
public:
    explicit MyClass(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) {}
};

#endif // MYCLASS_H

myclass.cpp:
#include "myclass.h"

main.cpp:
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.addImportPath("qrc:/");

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/src/myqmlobject.qml")));

    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}

qmldir:
module MyQmlDll
MyClass 1.0 myclass
MyQmlObject 1.0 myqmlobject.qml

myqmlobject.qml:
import QtQuick 2.15

Item {
    width: 200
    height: 200
    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "red"
    }
}

Main project:
MainP.Pro:
QT += quick

QML_IMPORT_PATH += $$PWD/../MyLibrary/lib

LIBS += -L$$PWD/../MyLibrary/lib/MyQmlDll.dll

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp

resources.files = main.qml 
resources.prefix = /$${TARGET}
RESOURCES += resources

main.cpp:
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.addImportPath("./../MyLibrary/lib");
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/MainP/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(
        &engine,
        &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
        &app,
        [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
            if (!obj && url == objUrl)
                QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
        },
        Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}

main.qml:
import QtQuick
import MyQmlDll 1.0

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    MyClass {
    }
    MyQmlObject {
    }
}


Is the DLL in a folder included in the PATH? Or otherwise in the same folder as the executable?

yes, I copied dll into exe (debug version) folder. but same problem

What we need to know are the contents of your MyLibrary.pro, MyLibrary/qml.qrc, and MyLibrary/qmldir files. The addImportPath function isn't meant to be used to add a DLL path; rather, it specifies your module's root directory where the qmldir is located, whether it is an external path or located within resources. By the way, your MyLibrary/main.cpp also doesn't have any relevance here, since you just want to use it as a library/external module. Also, MyClass isn't included in the qmldir either, which makes it unnecessary in this context.

I suggest that you take a look at the documentation at https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html.

I Updated question with MyLibrary.pro. Same problem remains (i removed in my code what you suggested)

I did a step over now, I forget to introduce DEFINES += MYLIBRARY_LIBRARY in MyLibrary.pro, declare MyClass as MYLIBRARY_EXPORT and i move from msvc compiler to mingw.
Now i need to share MyRectangle.qml contained in dll to main project. how can I do that?
